# Trying to upgrade to macOS sierra from OS X 10.8.5

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade

Every time I've tried to download macOS sierra from the app store I'm getting this message: "macOS sierra failed to download. Use purchases page to try again".

I've rebooted my computer many times and tried clearing the app store cache. I just tried resetting the application from the debug menu and set the logging level to 2. I'm seeing these phrases a few times throughout the logs:

```
02/25/17 12:10:06.560 DownloadOperation: Download failed with error: Error Domain=ISErrorDomain Code=3 "URL Error" UserInfo=0x7ff5d204ae90 

02/25/17 12:10:06.561 absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier "com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra" path "(null)"
```

Does anyone know anything else I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so everyone knows, I was finally able to download Sierra on a different network. It might've been something related to my ISP.